# Display alert box again and again

Tags: javascript, alert

I want to display alert box again and again even after clicking **ok** button in java script. How to achieve this in java script.

Comment: Sounds kind of annoying...

Comment: This is the exact reason why browsers now allow the user to prevent multiple successive alert windows.

Comment: I agree with @Antti29 said, voting to close

Comment: They did it here : https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/a/alert.htm . No matter how much you click on it, it will never disappear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call a function recursively, for example:

```
function myFunc() {
    alert("Alert Box");
    myFunc();
}

myFunc();
```

Answer (score 1):

Show it inside `window.setInterval` method.

ex:

```
function showHello() { 
   alert("Hello")
};

var alertFunc = window.setInterval(; showHello(), 3000); //1000 = 1sec
```

This code will show alert in every 3 seconds. If you wanna stop alerting just call following method

```
window.clearInterval(alertFunc);
```